# When i am closing an opportunity with 'stage = 1. Understand Customer', I am getting an popup in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have an opportunity with following details:
`Opportunity Step = 1`. Understand Customer

When I am trying to close this opportunity from UI, I am getting an popup saying:

Term is required and must be greater than zero before the opportunity can be closed.
The options to choose from: Add Products or Continue.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this, it this is a part of standard **salesforce** functionality?

Thanks,
Chirag

Comment: i want to add an image to clarify my question, how can i do this ?

Comment: Image link: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4xCZ6vqOuylSmF4MmxiQnV2cVU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Could you please upload your image in screencast and post the URL here. Or you also have an image option above the body part of the block provided to post your question. Check it out.